# rpm -R verses zypper info --requires

Tags: rpm, dependencies, zypper

Consider the following:

```
root# rpm -qR foobar
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsLzma) <= 4.4.6-1

root# zypper info --requires foobar
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

Information for package foobar:
-------------------------------
Respository: @System
Name: foobar
...
Requires: java-1_7_0-openjdk
```

So why the *hell* does Zypper say that Java is required, but RPM thinks that Java isn't required?

More to the point, why did Zypper install this package and *not* install Java?? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the answer is simple. In the RPM spec file, the `Requires:` tag was being misinterpreted as part of the `%description` section. The output above actually reads

```
Description:
...
Requires: java-1_7_0-openjdk
```

That makes it *look* like Zypper is saying the package requires Java, but *actually* it's just literal text in the description field. Grr!

Moved `Requires:` to the correct section in the spec file, now everything is fine.